# Why are text files saved in utf-8 bigger than the other?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

What is UTF-8 encoding and why are text files saved in utf-8 bigger than the other?

For example I had typed 'A' in the notepad and save it in UTF-8 format.

After that, The file size turns to: 4 bytes.

Why?

Answer (score 6):

It's almost certainly because whatever you're using to save the file is also including the [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) which in UTF-8 is 0xEF 0xBB 0xBF.

As for what UTF-8 is - it's a Unicode encoding which uses progressively more bytes for higher Unicode values; importantly, ASCII characters are stored as single bytes (the same bytes as they would be in ASCII). So any ASCII file is also a UTF-8 file with the same text. [This web page](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html) has more, as does [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

Answer (score 2):

Because a BOM (byte order mark) was inserted at the start of the file.

The BOM is a special character U+FEFF meant not to have any meaning except as a way to detect the encoding of a file.  You can read about it here:  http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#BOM

In the case of UTF-8, the BOM is encoded as \xEF \xBB \xBF which is where the 3 extra bytes come from.  Notepad and other text editors look for the BOM to guess the encoding of the file.  If it sees \xFF \xFE it will assume it is UCS-2 encoded in little endian format.  A \xFE \xFF means UCS-2 encoded in big endian format.

Comment: What is the BOM ,Please Explain More.

Comment: How about searching for "UTF-8 BOM" with a search engine of your choice? First hit.

Comment: BOM is a TLA for Byte Order Mark.  It makes it possible to determine if the file is saved little endian or big endian.

Comment: It makes it possible to determine if a **UTF-16** file is saved little endian or big endian.  UTF-8 only has one byte order.

Answer (score 2):

that's only because of the BOM, byte order mark. UTF-8 only expands characters that have a numeric value greater than 127 (non-ASCII).

not all text editors do this. Notepad is notorious for it (the useless UTF-8 BOM).