# Numpy - loadtxt and using converter for date

Tags: python, numpy

I want to load a txt which has the following formatting:

```
20-Sep-13,178.90,185.83,178.56,183.39,13401689
19-Sep-13,170.80,180.47,169.08,177.92,15594568
18-Sep-13,167.07,167.45,164.20,166.22,5439615
17-Sep-13,165.08,168.42,163.36,166.23,5500719
```

Therefor I use the following Python line:

```
date, closep, highp, lowp, openp, volume = np.loadtxt(stockFile, delimiter=',', unpack=True, converters={0: mdates.strpdate2num('%d-%b-%y')})
```

But I get the following error:

```
failed main loop time data '\xef\xbb\xbf20-Sep-13' does not match format '%d-%b-%y'
```

Does anyone know, what I'm doing wrong?

Thx,
Maecky

Comment: Looks like your text file has some extra characters at the beginning of each line ("\xef\xbb\xbf"). I'm not sure what format these characters are. Are you able to regenerate your text file to exclude these?

Comment: [UTF-8 BOM Byte Order Mark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870396/utf8-encoding)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text file contain UTF-8 BOM characters. [`numpy.loadtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) does not accept `encoding`, but you can pass iterable instead of filename.

Try following:

```
stockFile = '....'


import numpy as np
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import codecs

with codecs.open(stockFile, encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    date, closep, highp, lowp, openp, volume = np.loadtxt(f, delimiter=',', unpack=True, converters={0: mdates.strpdate2num('%d-%b-%y')})
```