# Plotting txt file with date, time and value data

Tags: python, date, time, load

I am pretty new to Python programing and have already been confronted with a problem that drives me insane. I kept on searching for the problem - even here at stack overflow. However, I didn't get any solution to solve my problem, which made me sign up for this site.

Nevertheless, this is my problem:

I have several txt files, that contain 3 columns. The first one can be neglected, the second one contains a mixture of date and time, separated with the letter "T" and the third column contains the value (pressure, temperature, what so ever).

Now, what I want to do is, to plot the second column (time and date) on the x axis and the value on the y axis.

I've tried MANY codes - also some are described here at stack overflow - but none of them was the one I was searching for and brought the right results.

More detailed, this is what a my txt files look like:

# MagPy ASCII
234536326.456,2014-06-17T14:23:00.000000,459.7463393940044
674346235.235,2014-06-17T14:28:00.000000,462.8783040474751
and so on.

Forget about the first column. Only the second and third one are relevant. So here, I guess, I have to skip the first line (and the first column), right?

HOWEVER - and here comes the part I cannot solve - with this "T" inside the second column, this becomes a string format. 
One of my many errors I get is: could not convert string to float

Well, I searched stack overflow and came across the following code:

```
 x, y = np.loadtxt('example.txt', dtype=int, delimiter=',',
              unpack=True, usecols=(1,2))

 plt.plot(x, y)

 plt.title('example 1')
 plt.xlabel('D')
 plt.ylabel('Frequency')
 plt.show()
```

I edited the "usecols" to 1 and 2, but with this code, I get the error: list index out of range

So, it doesn't matter what I do, I get an error any time. And the only thing I want is a plot (with matplotlib), that contains time and date on the x axis and the value (e.g. 459.7463393940044 from above) on the y axis. 
And talking about what I need: At the end, I have to put several diagrams (about 4-6), that were generated with MANY txt file data, in one figure.

Please, can anyone help me with this? I'd appreciate your help a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This is numpy datetime format.  You need to add an explicit converter for the datetime field.  The [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html) contains additional format details.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18959121/numpy-loadtxt-and-using-converter-for-date) question shows how to fill in the **converters** argument.

```
date, closep, highp, lowp, openp, volume = 
    np.loadtxt(f, delimiter=',', unpack=True, 
        converters={0:mdates.strpdate2num('%d-%b-%y')})
```

Is that enough to lead you to a full solution?

Comment: Ok. Somehow my answer appears above yours!?

Comment: Not a problem.  They're generally sorted by up-votes; I don't know how ties are resolved.  You can probably look this up in the **Meta** group -- where any future discussion should go.

Answer (score 0):

First, thanks for your response! Unfortunately, this doesn't work at all. I tried it with your converter and combined it with my code, but it didn't work out well. I tried then this code:

```
# Converter function
datefunc = lambda x: mdates.date2num(datetime.strptime(x, '%d %m %Y %H %M %S'))

# Read data from 'file.dat'
dates, levels = np.genfromtxt('BMP085_10085001_0001_201508.txt',    # Data to be read
                          delimiter=19,  # First column is 19 characters wide
                          converters={1: datefunc}, # Formatting of column 0
                          dtype=float,   # All values are floats
                          unpack=True)   # Unpack to several variables

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

# Configure x-ticks
ax.set_xticks(dates) # Tickmark + label at every plotted point
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'))

ax.plot_date(dates, levels, ls='-', marker='o')
ax.set_title('title')
ax.set_ylabel('Waterlevel (m)')
ax.grid(True)

# Format the x-axis for dates (label formatting, rotation)
fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=45)
fig.tight_layout()

fig.show()
```

And I get an    list index out of range error again. Seriously, I do not know any possible solution to make it look like that in the end: {[Plot date and time (x axis) versus a value (y axis) using data from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15261260/plot-date-and-time-x-axis-versus-a-value-y-axis-using-data-from-file)} - see diagram on the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I've had success doing the following. First, it's ok to read in your ISO8601 date as a string (so a basic read a line and split on comma will work). To convert the date string to a datetime object you can use

```
import dateutil   

# code to read in date_strings and my_values as lists goes here ...

# Here's the magic to parse the ISO8601 strings and make them into datetime objects

my_dates = dateutil.parser.parse(date_strings)

# Now plot the results

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)    
ax.plot_date(x=my_dates, y=my_values, marker='o', linestyle='')
ax.set_xlabel('Time')
```